# Are scrapy definitions (self, response) limited or require special function in order to parse multiple URLs in a loop?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am parsing two lists of URLs with the latter being populated from the first. I am able to get all the needed URLs, but having trouble pulling data from the last list of URLs. I am only able to get one URL's data

I have tried using scrapy.Request, response.follow, While statement, but only getting a response from one URL. I am new to scrapy/python not to sure how to fix this issue.

```
import scrapy



class DBSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "Scrape"
 allowed_domains = ["192.168.3.137"]
 start_urls = [
 'http://192.168.3.137/api/?controller_id=' + str(x)
 for x in range(0,8)
 ]

 def parse(self, response):
  for sites in response.xpath('//* 
   [@id="siteslist"]//li/a/@href').extract(): 
   yield response.follow(sites, self.parse_sites)

 def parse_sites(self, response):
  for device_pages in response.xpath('//* 
   [@id="list_devices"]/a/@href').extract():
   yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(device_pages), 
   self.parse_macs)

 def parse_macs(self, response):
  print response.url #only gets one response url
```

parse_mac only print one response url. should be equivalent to the amount of urls in devices_pages loop in parse_sites def

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code, and consider providing a simplified version of your code that still allows to reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check (e.g. with [logging](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html)) the return value of `response.xpath('//* 
   [@id="list_devices"]/a/@href').extract()`. If it does return a list with multiple URLs, check your logs to see if those URLs are being skipped for some reason (e.g. being invalid, duplicate URLs, etc.).